# Chrome prefs to download pdf silently

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I can't set up chrome prefs to download file silently

```
"safebrowsing.enabled": "true", 
"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
"download.prompt_for_download": "false",
"download.default_directory": "../../../../Attachments",
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": true
"download.extensions_to_open": "pdf",
```

Last line is a problem.
If i keep it - pdf file downloads silently, but it opens automatically in new window, which doesn't suit me
If i remove it - i got a dialog window, despite all other prefs, what is strange

Would you kindly explain what is wrong?

PS Also I use this args

```
"--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection",
"--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist"
```

PSS Chrome Version 120.0.6099.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)